# Random Dice not reseeding

Tags: c++, random, srand

I created the following function to create random numbers for a dice game

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "dice.h"
#include "display.h"
using namespace std;
int die[6][10];
void dice(int times, int dice){
    int r;
    for(int x=0;x<times;x++){
        for(int x=0;x<dice;x++){
            srand(time(0));
            r=(rand() % 5);
            die[r][x]+=1;
            cout<<"Die #"<<x+1<<" rolled a "<<r<<endl;
        }
    }

}
```

It doesn't reseed though. It just outputs the same number for each die. Does anyone know how I could fix it?

Comment: Note, too, that you don't need parentheses around `rand() % 5`. Also, that expression produces values from to to 4, so `die[5]` will never get hit. To avoid this kind of mistake, use a constant to define the number of faces (instead of hard-coding 6 and 5), and use that constant in the array definition and as the divisor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

srand() in a function that is called repeatedly, or a loop is no good.

Put your call to srand() in main. Only call it once per program.

Comment: This answer obviously solves the problem, but doesn't do a good job of describing what caused the problem. The issue is that `time()` is returning the same value because it's being called so rapidly that not enough time has passed for it to produce the next time value. If more time passes between the calls then the values used to seed the RNG, and the resulting values from `rand()` will look more random.

Comment: Although this wouldn't really be using the RNG to generate a random series of numbers, you'd just be getting the first value from each series. This will not necessarily have the same statistical properties as seeding the RNG once and then calling `rand()` many times to retrieve successive values generated by the RNG.

Comment: I was really short with explaining. My apologies for that. Stating it that way was a little too matter of fact. There are actually instances where you may want srand in a function with some known seed or passed variable seed. The only thing that comes to mind... Say you made a game with randomly generated levels. You could allow users to provide the seed to srand, and if none is provided use something like time, or /dev/urandom on a Linux machine. There are many better ways to seed srand than time(), but you give up portability.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using the srand and rand functions correctly. You are supposed to 'seed' the random number generator once, and then use `rand()` to retrieve successive values from the RNG. Each seed results in a particular sequence of numbers that fits certain randomness criteria.

Instead, you seed the random number generator each time, and then retrieve the first value in the random sequence. Since `time()` is called so rapidly that it returns the same seed, you are effectively resetting the random number generator back to the beginning of the same sequence, and therefore you get the same number you got before.

Even if the value returned by `time()` updated quickly enough that you got a new seed each time, you still would not be guaranteed good random numbers. The random number generator is designed to produce a sequence of numbers where that sequence has certain statistical properties. However there's no guarantee that the same properties hold over values chosen from *different* sequences.

So to use a deterministic random number generator you should seed the generator only once and then consume the sequence of values produced by that one seed.

---

Another point; the random number generators used to implement `rand()` have not historically been very good, `rand()` is not re-entrant or thread safe, and transforming the values produced by `rand()` into values with your desired distribution is not always straightforward.

In C++ you should prefer the `<random>` library which provides much better features. Here's an example of using `<random>`.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const int sides = 6;
    int groups = 10, dice_per_group = 3;

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> distribution(1,sides); // create an object that uses randomness from an external source (provided later) to produces random values in the given (inclusive) range

    // create and seed the source of randomness
    std::random_device r;
    std::seed_seq seed{r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r(), r()};
    std::mt19937 engine(seed);

    for (int i=0; i<groups; ++i) {
        for (int j=0; j<dice_per_group; ++j) {
            // use the distribution with the source of randomness
            int r = distribution(engine);
            std::cout << "Die #" << j+1 << " rolled a " << r << '\n';
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only want to call srand() once for any simulation you are doing. The reason for this is that with each call, you reseed rand(), which imposes a bias on your rand() values.  This is especially important if you are assuming i.i.d.

In the case above, you want to move srand() out of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You only want to call srand() once. So little time is passing that time() is returning the same value. So the random number generator starts at the same place.

Call srand before the function if possible, or a the beginning of it.